# Clickable link in email sent with the Trigger Email firebase extension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, handlebars.js

I am currently using the [Trigger Email extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) from Firebase to send emails whenever someone is invited to use the app by another user. I configured everything correctly and it is working perfectly except for one thing which is clickable links in the email.

I am using [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) with a template which is defined within a Firestore document. The template is made with HTML and looks like this:

```
<p>Hello {{invitedUser.firstName}},</p>
<p>You've been invited by {{user.fullName}} to join them on App Name here. By clicking on the link below you can accept this invitation.</p>
<p><a>{{inviteUrl}}</a></p>
<p>Best,<br>App Name here</p>
```

The email will be delivered but the inviteUrl is not clickable, it does display the url within the email. I also tried it using three brackets like {{{inviteUrl}}}.

I have also tried the following:

```
<p>Hello {{invitedUser.firstName}},</p>
<p>You've been invited by {{user.fullName}} to join them on App Name here. By clicking on the link below you can accept this invitation.</p>
<p><a href="{{inviteUrl}}">Accept invitation</a></p>
<p>Best,<br>App Name here</p>
```

But in this case the email is not delivered at all.. I don't know whats going wrong there. If I do the same but define a url directly instead of using inviteUrl the url is displayed but not clickable.

I have also seen some weird cases where I pasted a html example of a link online in my html and it worked and it stopped working whenever I modified the url, even when I changed the url back to the original one which was working before.

Using helpers for handlebars is not really an option as far as I have read as I am using the Trigger Email extension.

Maybe something is going wrong with storing the HTML in a string field in Firestore but I tried everything I know which is why I am asking this question here.

Comment: The link is clickable in 2nd way but what do you mean by email is not being sent? Do you get any errors in Firebase Functions logs ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj According to the logs it was sent successfully but it was never delivered to my inbox

Comment: I'd try setting the content to `html: 'This is a <a href="https://google.com">hyperlink</a> in an email.'`  to check if this has something to do with handlebars

Comment: @Dharmaraj That works, but as soon as I replace the url with the inviteUrl variable the email will not be delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found the answer myself...

I was creating the Firestore mail objects from node js and the url I was using  was of type `any`, casting it to `String` made it work.

The data object was:

```
{
    inviteUrl: dynamicLink,
}
```

Changing it to this fixed it:

```
{
    inviteUrl: String(dynamicLink),
}
```

The working html is:

```
<a href="{{inviteUrl}}">Accept invitation</a>
```